# How to better handle events

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have multiple events on an element I am currently handling those events as written here:

```
$("body").on("click", ".element", function(e) {
    // Do something on click
});

$("body").on("change", ".element", function(e) {
    // Do something on change
});
```

Is there a way to combine all the events on an element in one `on()` call? What is the best practice if there are multiple events associated with one element?

```
$("body").on("change click", ".element", function(e) {
    // Can I detect here if it was change or click event and perform an action accordingly?
});
```

Comment: try `e.type` to figure out which event kind was triggered

Comment: Have a look at https://api.jquery.com/event.type/

Comment: but is it a best practice or better approach than what I am currently using?

Comment: @APatel it depends on how you want to react to the events. If the reaction is very different, IMHO it is better to keep them separate, instead of having a big IF statement at the beginning of the callback that wraps it all...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `type` property of the event to determine which logic to execute:

```
$('body').on('change click', '.element', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'click') {
        // do something...
    } 
    else if (e.type == 'change') {  
        // do something else...
    }
});
```

Alternatively you can provide an object to `on` which contains the functions to bind with the event type names as the keys:

```
$('body').on({
    click: function() {
        // do something on click...
    },
    change: function() {
        // do something on change...
    }
}, '.element');
```

Personally I would use the latter method. The whole point of having a unified `on()` handler is negated when using a rather ugly `if` statement to split the event types.

Comment: which one is best practice?  using it separately or combining all events in one and handling it? does it make any difference in terms of performance or re-usability?

Comment: Added a little note to the question for you.

Answer (score 5):

Yes! jQuery passes the event object which contain the event information:

```
$("body").on("change click", ".element", function(e) {
    console.log(e.type);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `event.type`. Some will say it's bad practice and others may find it useful.

```
$("body").on("change click", ".element", function(event) {
    switch (event.type) {
        case 'click':

        break;
        case 'change':

        break;
        default:
    }
});
```

[jQuery event.type](https://api.jquery.com/event.type/)

Answer (score 3):

```js
$('#element').on('keyup keypress blur change', function(event) {
    alert(event.type); // keyup OR keypress OR blur OR change
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="element" />
```